# Where is Spring Roo console in IntelliJ nowadays?

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-roo

I saw many messages about Spring Roo console in IntelliJ, but can't find any traces of Roo in reality:

[image]

Where is it? Or what is instead of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays, the Spring Roo shell is beeing maintained by [DISID](http://www.disid.com) and the only official tool tested to work with Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 is the [Spring Tool Suite (STS)](https://spring.io/tools).

If you're interested about how to work with Spring Roo using the STS IDE, follow the Spring Roo documentation about how to include the Spring Roo plug-in into your STS distribution.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/#getting-started-install-roo

On the other hand, I found some (really old) posts about Spring Roo and IntelliJ:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/04/new-in-105-spring-roo-console/
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/13.0/working-with-spring-roo-console.pdf

But as I've said before, this is not the official and maintained tool to work with the Spring Roo shell.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Spring Roo support has been dropped in IntelliJ IDEA since version 15.